# power bi: how to add common date slicer that filters on two or three charts data based on date

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

How to add common date slicer which will filter two or three charts data based on date column of those charts

i have tried to create a date table and applied relation and when i used date slicer it is showing empty data even though  data is there in the mentioned dates range

I need to create a common date filter for three charts present in power bi report. three charts using three different tables and with different columns we dont have any relation between them. But all three tables have a date column so Now i need to create a common date slicer so that i can filter using that and results should be generated

slicer should filter data of multiple charts.

Comment: Can you please share 1) a sample of your data; 2) a screengrab of your model diagram; 3) any relevant code you've tried, highlighting what works and where things go wrong; and 4) a mockup of your expected outcome?

Comment: this is a simple requirement of adding common date filter for multiple charts which are not having any relation but having date columns

Comment: If the tables have no relationships, they cannot be mutually filtered by a single slicer without writing a DAX measure for each aggregate. No one can actually do that if they don't know what the model looks like. You are correct that it is a simple requirement, but you've not accepted the provided answer. For anyone to provide more detailed responses, we need more detail from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best suggestion is to build your own date table in Power BI. You can take a look at this post [here](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/reference-date-table-in-dax-and-power-bi/) for more details.

Now you might end up having to normalize the dates in your existing tables as well to ensure that you are linking all tables on a common date type.